# How to get the dll file of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 2.2.6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-standard

C:\Users\sravya-6606.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite\2.2.6\lib\netstandard2.0

Comment: Install from nuget to your project and rebuild?

Comment: I am developing a .Net Standard library using Entity framework, When I generate the .dll file of the library and refer it in an UWP application. Then, I find the entity framework missing. Could you help me on this.

Comment: I think you should install entity framework from NuGet in projects which are using your .Net Standard library

Comment: I tried it this way but this doesn't work still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754503/how-to-refer-to-entityframeworkcore-from-nuget-package-source-for-a-uwp-project