# How to Refer to EntityFrameworkCore from Nuget Package source for a UWP Project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uwp, .net-standard

I downloaded .nupkg file from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.2.6 and added in the folder which I referred from the Nuget Package Sources.

But it says that Microsoft.DependencyInjections 2.2.0 not Found. Then, I added the nupkg for MicrosoftDependencyInjections 2.2.0 from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.2.0

In runtime execution, it shows Microsoft.DependencyInjections 2.2.0 not found!.

How to get rid of this issue,

Comment: Hello, please download the nuget package from [Nuget Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using this package in a .Net Standard  library which I am packaging into .dll file, which I am using inside an other UWP application. Then I am getting the that "entity framework core is not found", So, I want to refer to the packages from a folder. Please hep me with this.

Comment: To reference the nuget package from the folder, in addition to downloading the corresponding package, you need to set the package source in Visual Studio. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) to set